# Laravel make directory fails with storage_path

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Am using faker an i would like to generate images and save them but am getting an error

```
mkdir(): No such file or directory
```

So i have

```
$factory->define(App\User::class, function (Faker $faker) {
$filepath = storage_path('images/fakerusr/'); //this fails
 if(!File::exists($filepath)){
     File::makeDirectory($filepath);  
 };
return [
    'profile_pic' => $faker->image($filepath,400,300)

];
```

});

BUt when i use

```
$filepath = public_path('images/fakerusr/'); //this works
```

But the path saved in the db starts from ./var/www... but i would like the path from images in the public folder.

I have added both read and write permissions to public folder

```
sudo chmod a+rw -R /var/www.../public
```

How do i go about this.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the images and child directory fakerusr already exists. By default the unix command [mkdir](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mkdir) requires the `-p` flag to "Create intermediate directories as required" and the PHP function [mkdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php) also requires the 3rd parameter to be `true` to create nested directories . `File::makeDirectory` probably works this way too.

Answer (score 0):

you can check using `Storage::has`

```
  $directory='images/fakerusr';
    if (!Storage::has($directory)) {

       $resp= Storage::makeDirectory($directory);
       dd($resp);
    } else{
        echo "already exist";
    };
```

Also note that directory will be created inside `storage\app\`  .And make sure you have 755 permission to these folders

if you want to create directory inside public folder

```
 $directory='images/fakerusr';
    if (File::isDirectory($directory)) {

       echo "already exist";
    } else{
        $result = File::makeDirectory($directory, 0775, true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$filepath = storage_path('images/fakerusr/'); //this fails
        if(!File::exists($filepath)){
            File::makeDirectory($filepath, 0755, true, true);
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

For Check Directory Exists or Not And making the Directory as Public, I am using..

```
use Illuminate\Http\File;

$path = public_path('upload/imgaes');

if(!File::isDirectory($path)){
    File::makeDirectory($path, 0777, true, true);
}
```

> Hope this work